# how to control the order of overlap of polygons in kmz

Tags: overlap, google-earth, kmz

I have multiple polygons and lines stored in different folders,in this specific project. Even in classifying things I want to show on top of my image, on the bottom of my list, it seems not to work. Is that due to the quantity of folders I'm using? How can I make it happen the way I want ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The order of polygons can be enforced by adding `<gx:drawOrder>` element (which is a [Google Earth KML extension](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kmlextensions)).

Note the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxdraworder) (see below) only specifies LineStrings but also works for Lines, LinearRings, and Polygons. Anywhere "LineStrings" is mentioned below just replace it with Lines, Rings, and Polygons. The drawOrder support for Polygons is undocumented but was reported as an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/issues/detail?id=423).

KML Documentation:

> `<gx:drawOrder>`
>
> "An integer value that specifies the order for drawing multiple *line
>   strings*. *LineStrings* drawn first may be partially or fully obscured by *LineStrings* with a later (or higher) draw order. This element may be required in
>   conjunction with the `<gx:outerColor>` and `<gx:outerWidth>` elements in
>   `<LineStyle>` when dual-colored lines cross each other."

In example below, a Red polygon is drawn over the blue polygon. To make the blue polygon draw over the red one change its drawOrder value to a higher number.

```
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Red Polygon</name>
            <description>gx:drawOrder=3</description>
            <Style>
              <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
              </LineStyle>
              <PolyStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
              </PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <Polygon>
                <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                        14.456906,37.345497,0 14.949769,37.346531,0
                        14.960918,37.987563,0 14.45089,37.987521,0
                        14.456906,37.3455,0 
                    </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>        

        <Placemark>
            <name>Blue Polygon</name>
            <description>gx:drawOrder=2</description>
            <Style>
              <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
              </LineStyle>
              <PolyStyle>
                <color>ffff0000</color>
              </PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <Polygon>
                <gx:drawOrder>2</gx:drawOrder>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                        14.83626,38.016863,0 14.835535,37.645589,0
                        15.47025,37.589266,0 15.470457,38.019158,0
                        14.83626,38.016862,0 
                    </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
 </kml>
```